# whenever executing snowflake procedure 'associate_tag_batch' via python script getting error?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

whenever executing the procedure 'associate_tag_batch" via script getting error?

when i execute procedure 'associate_tag_batch' in the snowflake worksheet , it is executed successfully.

```
call associate_tag_batch('my_temporary_classification_table');
```

however executing same procedure via script getting error "SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b19e8e-3200-fa49-0000-000787b2ca75: 100131 (P0000): JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in ASSOCIATE_TAG_BATCH at ' out[name] = results.getColumnValue(1).split('' position 48"

i tried below script,

```
assing_tag_result = conn.sql(

        "call associate_tag_batch('my_temporary_classification_table');"

    ).collect()
```

expecting procedure result supposed to be in json like

```
{
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"COMPANIES\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"CUSTOMER\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 5 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 5 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"MY_TEMPORARY_CLASSIFICATION_TABLE\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 0 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 0 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"PERSONS\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"STUDENTS\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ]
}
```

however getting error  **"SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b19e8e-3200-fa49-0000-000787b2ca75: 100131 (P0000): JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in ASSOCIATE_TAG_BATCH at ' out[name] = results.getColumnValue(1).split('' position 48"**

i tried below script,

```
assing_tag_result = conn.sql(

        "call associate_tag_batch('my_temporary_classification_table');"

    ).collect()
```

expecting procedure result supposed to be in json like

```
{
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"COMPANIES\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"CUSTOMER\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 5 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 5 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"MY_TEMPORARY_CLASSIFICATION_TABLE\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 0 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 0 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"PERSONS\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ],
  "my_db.my_schema2.\"STUDENTS\"": [
    "Applied tag semantic_category to 2 columns.",
    "Applied tag privacy_category to 2 columns."
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error is coming from the stored procedure itself and not Snowpark, therefore I am wondering how come it works in a worksheet. Are you able to provide a sample of the stored procedure code?